# Makefile on Windows 10 - file not found

Tags: python, makefile

After some time I finally managed to successfully install python and pip and run it on my machine using Visual Studio Code.

I am working in virtual environment in python and we have a `Makefile` with following statement:

```
test:
    source .env && PYTHONPATH=. PY_ENV=testing py.test ${ARGS} --duration=20
```

File `.env` lives in the main directory next to `Makefile`. It contains some environmental variables needed for testing certain APIs.

When I take the line out of the file and run it in my terminal, everything works fine and all tests are running etc.

However if I call the following: `make test` I am getting this error:

```
$ make test
source .env && PYTHONPATH=. PY_ENV=testing py.test  --duration=20
/usr/bin/sh: line 0: source: .env: file not found
make: *** [test] Error 1
(venv)
```

To me it looks like when running this command from within `Makefile` it can't see the `.env` file but have no idea how to solve it.

Comment: did you try with `/full/path/to/.env` ? On Linux you could also use `pwd` to see in which directory it is executed. And `ls` to see what files/folders are available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `source` command isn't looking up the file in the current working directory. As mentioned in `man source`:

> Read and execute commands from filename in the current shell
>   environment and return the exit status of the last command executed
>   from filename.   If filename does not contain a slash, filenames in
>   PATH are used to find the directory containing filename.

Change the file path like so:

```
test:
    source ./.env && PYTHONPATH=. PY_ENV=testing py.test ${ARGS} --duration=20
```

---

Note that this error does not occur in bash version < 4. This is due to an implementation bug when run under POSIX mode (what `make` uses, since its default shell is `sh`, which is usually `bash --posix`). The correct behaviour was first mentioned in the documentation of bash-2.05 (revision 28ef6c31, file doc/bashref.info):

> When Bash is not in POSIX mode, the current directory is searched if
>   FILENAME is not found in `$PATH'.

These older versions searched the current directory regardless of POSIX mode. It was only in bash-4.0-rc1 (revision 3185942a, file general.c) that this was corrected. Running `git diff 3185942a~ 3185942a general.c` outputs this section:

```
@@ -69,6 +69,7 @@ posix_initialize (on)
   if (on != 0)
     {
       interactive_comments = source_uses_path = expand_aliases = 1;
+      source_searches_cwd = 0;
     }
```

Comment: Thank you, it's working now. Do you think it's a matter of OS as well since everybody else on Macs is using this file, also inside python's virtual environment and somehow it works for them?

Comment: It seems that macOS ships with bash-3.2, which has buggy behaviour. I added a note explaining the difference.